# Remove Duplicate Records While Retaining One Record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table of phone records as such:

```
ID  int (Primary Key)
company varchar 
dbaname varchar 
coaddress   varchar 
cocity  varchar 
costate varchar 
cozip   varchar 
phonenum    varchar
```

What I want to accomplish is to remove all the duplicates phone numbers (phonenum field) but retain one occurence.

When doing a duplicate check, I see there are over 41000 duplicate phone numbers in the table (total of about 141000).

How would I go about doing this based on the phone number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: This may not be as simple as it seems: a company may move from one address to the other, but keep the same phone number. So the real question is which of the multiple addresses would you rather throw away.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - That's a great point.  Any of the other data can be different, as business may move, etc.  I'm actually not concerned with any of the other data.  This is feeding a dialer, so the phone number is essentially what matters.  I don't want multiple agents calling the same phone number and fumbling over each other over the same lead.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 <joke>I tell you the answer if you promise to remove my number from your database</joke> If it does not matter which rows you'd rather keep, check out the answer that Martin Smith linked: it is nice and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep only the latest record:

```
DELETE  yourTable
FROM    yourTable T
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  MAX(ID) [ID]
            FROM    yourTable
            GROUP BY Phonenum
        ) MaxT
            ON MaxT.ID = T.ID
WHERE   MaxT.ID IS NULL
```

I'd definitely archive what you are deleting into another table though as there is no guarantee you are removing the correct record without checking manually or adding further criteria to the Delete statement.

Comment: I've made a complete back up prior to asking the question.  Learned my lesson long ago! :)